# Marshaling exported string vector from C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++

How can you marshal a vector of strings exported from a C++ dll ? I would like them to be separated before used in my C# program. Could you help me out ?

Comment: You can't, C++ objects are not directly usable in a C# program.  They are not even usable in another C++ program that was compiled with a different compiler.  There is no binary standard for C++.  You need glue code to convert them, written in the C++/CLI language.  A language that knows how to compile native C++ as well as managed code.

Comment: Or you can export a function that uses an array of `char*` instead of the vector.

Comment: This questions been asked similarly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102436/how-to-marshal-collection-in-c-sharp-to-pass-to-native-c-code

Comment: @Hans C# has the `MarshallAsAttribute`...

Comment: @ColeJohnson: `[MarshalAs(...)]` doesn't let you marshal stuff as much other than primitive types (ints and floats of various sizes, C strings, pointers, arrays...).  A native C++ class instance is a bit useless unless you know how a given compiler lays it out and/or where its member functions and vtables live; even if you could easily find that info, using it relies heavily on IB and effectively ties you to that compiler.

Comment: @cHao correct, but as for a `struct`, you should be fine using `[MarshallAs(...)]` if you know how the compiler pads word boundaries (typically 4)

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Many structs would be fine -- C++11, at least, has some rules about so-called "standard-layout" structs, that make it a bit more straightforward to marshal and consume the *contents* of a struct/class. In order for the rules to apply, though, you have to avoid much of what makes classes useful as more than just groupings of raw data. If your type uses `virtual`, has reference-type or non-standard-layout-type fields, has members defined in more than one class in the inheritance chain, or has any fields with different access control than the rest, you're back in IB land (or worse).

Comment: @cHao yep. Interacting between managed and unmanaged is suppose to be as simple as it can be, but unfortunately C and C++ are designed to be processor and OS independent. That creates some problems with compilers. Instead of using a de facto standard that isn't always followed, the big compiler people should get together and write up a standard for x86 (or x86-64) on how to pad objects and other things as a default. Having to check the compiler with macros and then defining macros about the packing is annoying. Even using `#pragma` is annoying as there is no standardized meaning behind it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can. Actually, not just `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::wstring`, any standard C++ class or your own classes can be marshaled or instantiated and called from C#/.NET.

Wrapping a `std::vector<any_type>` in C# is indeed possible with just regular P/Invoke Interop, it is complicated though. even a std::map of any type can be done in C#/.NET.

The basic idea of instantiating a C++ object from .NET world is to allocate exact size of the C++ object from .NET, then call the constructor which is exported from the C++ DLL to initialize the object, then you will be able to call any of the functions to access that C++ object, if any of the method involves other C++ classes, you will need to wrap them in a C# class as well, for methods with primitive types, you can simply P/Invoke them. If you have only a few methods to call, it would be simple, manual coding won't take long. When you are done with the C++ object, you call the destructor method of the C++ object, which is a export function as well. if it does not have one, then you just need to free your memory from .NET.

Here is an example.

```
public class SampleClass : IDisposable
{    
    [DllImport("YourDll.dll", EntryPoint="ConstructorOfYourClass", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,          CallingConvention=CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    public extern static void SampleClassConstructor(IntPtr thisObject);

    [DllImport("YourDll.dll", EntryPoint="DoSomething", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,      CallingConvention=CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    public extern static void DoSomething(IntPtr thisObject);

    [DllImport("YourDll.dll", EntryPoint="DoSomethingElse", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi,      CallingConvention=CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    public extern static void DoSomething(IntPtr thisObject, int x);

    IntPtr ptr;

    public SampleClass(int sizeOfYourCppClass)
    {
        this.ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeOfYourCppClass);
        SampleClassConstructor(this.ptr);  
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(this.ptr);
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse(int x)
    {
        DoSomethingElse(this.ptr, x);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(this.ptr);
    }
}
```

For the detail, please see the below link,

[C#/.NET PInvoke Interop SDK](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk/)

(I am the author of the SDK tool)

Comment: If you're worried about downvotes from people who _"simply just do not know how to do it"_, then you should include an example. If you don't explain how to do it, then you're not answering the question

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will include an simple example of how to do it.

Comment: Just added a simple example. Thanks!

Comment: A couple of issues: (1) The compiler isn't required to export the member functions that'd make the object useful; you'd have to somehow tell it to export them when building the DLL.  If the DLL is a third-party library... eh.  You're stuck with whatever API it provides. (2) The C and C++ calling conventions are not the same, especially when it comes to calling member functions.  Just *how* different they are, is implementation-specific.  Some expect `this` in `*cx`, some might want it on the stack, etc. If your DLL was written with VS, this might work.  Any other compiler?  Eh.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. For (1), Not really, if it is a template class and all the implementation is inside the header files, it can still be exported in a supplement even it is not exported in the original C++ DLL, if the implementation of the C++ class is inside of the CPP file and the class is not exported, you won't be able to access it even from C or C++ normally, right? For (2), that is where the calling convention comes  into play, you need to decorate the P/Invoke with correct calling convention, it is not just for C++ function, you need it for C style function as well.

Comment: For different compilers, yes, it is tough, but it is doable, but still, if you can call the C++ DLL in C++, yes, you can call it via P/invoke.

Comment: For other compilers, that's one place where the import library can help.  It can outwardly use the names and calling conventions your compiler expects, but then tweak things to match what the other compiler uses.

Comment: For the most part, though, it's considered a bad idea to expose a native C++ (non COM) interface in a public DLL at all, for all kinds of binary compatibility reasons.  It seems quite odd to me that any class in `std` is actually exposed in the DLL, and i'd think it'd cause all kinds of grief when the consumer says `#include <vector>` etc.

Comment: You are right, the std class does not get exported in a C++ DLL, because it is C++ run-time DLL already has it. That is why you can not use it from .NET directly, right? You do need to export instantiated template class though. When you include <vector> and say vector<int>, you instantiated vector<int> in your code, since it requires both C++ DLL and your application to use the same run-time, it is fine. But in .NET, you can not do that, you have to specifically export that instantiated template class from some where. It is not a bad idea, actually VS will warn you if you don't.

Comment: The compilers are not really an issue. For a code generator to figure out this should be an easy task comparing to all other difficulties. Based on my experience, it is really not that difficult. If you had experience of using the tool to generate C# wrapper dll automatically in a few seconds for a very complicated DLL and immediately use it under AnyCPU mode. You would be surprised to see how this works out so well. But, this is only my story. Thanks!