# How to marshal nested array from C# to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllexport

I am making a DLL in C++ to use in C#. I need to transfer a array list from C# to C++ vector. The array will look like

```
[][]
[][]
.
.
```

I referred to this answer for marshaling List to vector [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102436/how-to-marshal-collection-in-c-sharp-to-pass-to-native-c-code).
It worked for one dimension array. But for list of array which gives a nested array gives an error "There is no marshaling support for nested arrays".

My code looks like this on C# end,

```
    [DllImport("./x64/Debug/Test.dll")]
    public static extern void analysis([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] double[][] values, int len);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<double[]> lst = new List<double[]>();
        lst.Add(new double[] { 1.2, 1.3 });
        lst.Add(new double[] { 2.3, 2.4 });
        lst.Add(new double[] { 3.4, 3.5 });

        analysis(lst.ToArray(), lst.Count);

    }
```

And on C++ end,

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl analysis(double* values[], int len)
{
    using namespace std;

    vector<array<double,2>> ind(values, values + len);

    int n = ind.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << ind[i][0] << ind[i][1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Also, I am not sure I wrote the vector constructor correctly. I would very much appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1):

Try use json.
In c#:

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lst);
```

Then in C++ unserialize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).