# Marshalling C++ class as structure

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

On a C++ side I have following class declaration:

```
class MyClass {
    ...fields
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass(); };
```

This class is used in some methods inside dll. It passed to and returned from them.
How can I represent it in C#? I need to make it fully compatable with C++ dll.

This class has no methods only parameterless constructor and destructor are definded. Any ideas how to marshall it? Unfortunately, I can't use C++\CLI, but I hope it is possible to do it with C#.

Only one idea I have is to represent it like a structure on a C# side (I have no access to C++ code, unfortunately) and try to Marshal.PtrToStructure. But I'm not sure it will work.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: So the class is used only for its fields? It's identity doesn't matter? What does the destructor do?

Comment: You can marshall with Marshal.PtrToStructure, define the class with properties and contructor, destructor:
`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class MyClass
{
    ...fields
    MyClass();
    ~MyClass();
}`

Comment: @svick yeah, it's treated like a struct. Constructor initializes fields with default values, destructor nulls them.

Comment: This is not possible, C# cannot create an instance of the class and cannot destroy it.  The unmanaged memory allocator, size of the object and addresses of the constructor and destructor are implementation details of the C++ compiler that you can't get to in C#.  A C++/CLI wrapper is required.  Or you can expose the C++ class through COM.

Comment: @HansPassant An instance of the class exported in the C++ DLL can be created. The reason is that the constructor and destructor must be exported in the C++ DLL in order to be used even in the natice C++ code. Once you know the size of the class, you can allocate that size of the memory and pass to the constructor to initialize it. I have done a lot of C# wrapper for  C++ dll this way automatically. It works very well even with very complicated C++ DLL.

Comment: @dave - this is a vapid claim if you don't share with us how you did it.  The SO way is to post an answer instead of a comment.  Please emphasize how you measured the native object size and did so in a maintainable way.  A bit of focus on taking care of the __thiscall calling convention requirement would be welcome too.

Comment: @HansPassant, I did share the information on the other post. Here is the link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747171/c-sharp-pinvoke-marshalling-structure-containg-vectorstructure/16003004#16003004. For this particular question, size of the class/object can be calculated easily. Since there are only two methods, mangled names are fine to be used in P/Invoke.

Comment: There is no Santa Claus there.

Comment: There is no need for Santa Claus, it is just needed to be automated. Please read my blog. [PInvoke Interop SDK](http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk/)

Comment: If you really want to marshal the class to structure, please pay attention to the destructor, if it is a virtual destructor, a pointer to the virtual function table will be created for that class, which means your structure will have one more pointer larger than the total of all the fields in the class. A pointer is either 4 bytes on x86 or 8 bytes on x64.

Comment: Both constructor and destructor are exported in the C++ DLL because you would need to call them via "new" and "delete" keywords from c++ code as well. The only missing part is the size of the class, a C++ compiler will have to calculate the size of the class based on the header file and the version of the C++ runtime. The last thing is that even you call the C++ DLL from C++, you can not mix it with different version of C++ runtime DLL, it is true to a C# wapper, it is true to C++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really possible in C#.  It can map pieces of data between managed and native but not behavior.  A C++ class inherently provides behavior and hence can't be marshalled directly.

What you can do though is marshal an `IntPtr` to the native object and create a thin PInvoke layer that just uses the `IntPtr` to access pieces of data on the type.  For example lets say I had the following C++ class.

```
class MyClass {
public:
  int Field;
};
```

I could expose it's behavior with the following set of C functions.

```
extern "C" {

  void* MyClass_Create() {
    return new MyClass();
  }

  void MyClass_Delete(void* pValue) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(pValue);
  }

  int MyClass_GetField(void* pValue) {
    return reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(pValue)->Field;
  }

  void MyClass_SetField(void* pValue, int field) {
    reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(pValue)->Field = field;
  }
}
```

Now that I've exposed this via C functions I can create a thin managed wrapper on top of it

```
internal static class NativeMethods {
  [DllImport("example.dll")]
  internal static extern IntPtr MyClass_Create();

  [DllImport("example.dll")]
  internal static extern void MyClass_Destroy(IntPtr ptr);

  [DllImport("example.dll")]
  internal static extern int MyClass_GetField(IntPtr prt);

  [DllImport("example.dll")]
  internal static extern void MyClass_SetField(IntPtr ptr, int field);
}


public class MyClass : IDisposable {
  private readonly IntPtr m_pointer;

  public int Field {
    get { return NativeMethods.MyClass_GetField(m_pointer); }
    set { NativeMethods.MyClass_SetField(m_pointer, value); }
  }

  public MyClass() {
    m_pointer = NativeMethods.MyClass_Create();
  }

  // Create from existing 
  public MyClass(IntPtr pointer) {
    m_pointer = pointer;
  }

  public void Dispose() {
    NativeMethods.MyClass_Destroy(m_pointer);
  }
}
```

Comment: All the non-pure-virtual and non-template methods of a C++ DLL are exported because they have to be used from C++ native code as well, So, you surely can call them from C# using calling convention of ThisCall. You don't necessarily wrap them in c style method.