# How to marshal a c++ class/struct which is a structure of Tree to C# class

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, marshalling

i has defined a class in c++
like:

```
class node{
    public: node();...
    public:
          node** childs;
          int id;
}
```

also defined in c#:

```
public class Node{
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.???)]//i don't know what it should be
      public System.IntPtr[] childs;//also
      public int id;
}
```

i used dllimport function to get a c++ class object pointer,and use

```
Node root = Marshal.PtrToStructue<Node>(p);
```

let root be a Node class defined in c#
but it cannot success,when i want to transform.
i think it may cause by the define of array in c++,or the use of marshal in c#.
i want to know how can i solve it .

the main problem is the nesting of class/struct (or double pointer)

thanks.

Comment: You can't marshal C++ classes anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045539/marshalling-c-class-as-structure You need some kind of middleware C++ function to map it into a struct at a pointer supplied by C#

Comment: @AlexF yes ,the childs should be an array of nodePtr, c# code:[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 3)]
    public System.IntPtr[] nodes;